# php: Get page contents with AJAX loaded

Tags: php, ajax

the page that i want to get from my php-script contains ajax. So when i do something like: 
file_get_contents($url);

i receive just the contents with javascript.

is it possible to get the page with all ajax executed?

Comment: Just to clarify: you are loading a page with `file_get_contents($url)` (btw. are you loading it from remote server?) that loades some content with AJAX and in result, you are getting JS source, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run javascript contents from javascript coming in through AJAX, you would have to run eval on the script, but you better make absolutely sure the javascript isn't "user-input", otherwise using that, you could have some serious security issues on your hands.

It's also not good practice to use eval - better to load a js file when you pull the contents through AJAX and have your AJAX success activate a function in the js file.